# What is the precise definition of a nonlinear signal?

Tags: signal-analysis

I tried to find the the precise definition of a nonlinear signal. However it is not easy. How can we define a nonlinear signal?

Comment: Do you really mean a nonlinear **signal**? Or maybe a nonlinear **system**?

Comment: I mean a nonlinear signal.

Comment: @cabal: The term really doesn't make much sense. Can you provide a reference where it's being used or did you come up with it yourself?

Comment: I found it in "Encyclopedia of Information Science and Technology". Here is the link to the definition: https://www.igi-global.com/dictionary/nonlinear-approach-brain-signal-modeling/36494

Comment: Well, the definition is there. A signal, that comes out of a nonlinear system. Refer to Matt's answer.

Comment: Signals are neither linear nor nonlinear. Linearity is a property of a system. Defining a non-linear signal as the output of a non-linear system is inane, since a linear system could have produced the same exact signal.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, the term *nonlinear signal* doesn't make much sense. If you refer to *nonlinear signal processing* then this is not about the processing of nonlinear signals, but about the nonlinear processing of signals, i.e., about the use of nonlinear systems.

A system $\mathcal{T}$ is nonlinear if it doesn't obey the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle). I.e., if $y_1(t)=\mathcal{T}\{x_1(t)\}$ is the response to input $x_1(t)$, and $y_2(t)=\mathcal{T}\{x_2(t)\}$ is the response to input $x_2(t)$ then

$$\mathcal{T}\big\{\alpha x_1(t)+\beta x_2(t)\big\}=\alpha\mathcal{T}\big\{x_1(t)\big\}+\beta\mathcal{T}\big\{x_2(t)\big\}$$

is generally *not* satisfied.

Well-known examples of such nonlinear systems are [median filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) and Volterra filters, but there are many trivial operations, such as taking the magnitude of a signal, which must be classified as nonlinear processing.

Answer (score 2):

Per https://www.igi-global.com/dictionary/nonlinear-approach-brain-signal-modeling/36494 it's defined as

> A nonlinear signal is generally defined as the signal generated by the
>   system that does not obey superposition and scaling properties.

You can certainly define it that way, but it seems like a useless definition since it doesn't reference any property of the signal itself.

Consider a case where you have a non-linear system followed by an linear "pass through" system. Per the definition, the output of the non-linear system would be a "non-linear signal" and the output of the pass-through would be a "linear" signal. Since the linear system is pass-through the input and output are the same, so now you have two signals that are identical but one of them is "non-linear" and the other one isn't. That really doesn't make any sense, so the definitions seem pointless and not useful for anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are materials where the strain/stress relationship becomes nonlinear at high signal amplitude that are studied in nonlinear acoustics.

The same can be true in optics where high amplitude fields changes a linear propagation to a nonlinear one.

I believe action potentials in nerves are nonlinear.

The term “small signal” has been associated with linear propagating signals.

I can’t say I’ve seen the terms linear or nonlinear signals used.